# PHP Version - difficulty coding for a lower version

Tags: php, mysql

My client is using PHP version 5.2.0, and I have some code that works perfectly, but uses 5.4.7 at the moment. When my code is run on their server, I receive a parse error. I've searched online for an alternative way to write this code, but I can't find anything. If anyone has any tips that would be a great help.

```
**$count = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM menuitem")->fetch_row()[0];** //I want to make sure the previous and next button are only displayed exactly to the number of items 
                                                                                  //in my database. I have to count those items, and turn that mysqli_query object into data. fetch_row[0] stores them
                                                                                  //in an array, starting at 0, turning it into an integer I can use to count below.
    $prev = $start - 3;
    if ($prev >= 0) {
        echo '<td><a href="?start=' . $prev . '">Previous Items</a></td>';// Set your $start - 3 since our offset is 3, and pass that to a variable.
    }                                                                     //if $start - 3 is still greater than 0, then display the previous button. Logically, that is page 2.

    $next = $start + 3;
    if ($next < $count) {
        echo '<td><a href="?start=' . $next . '">Next Items</a></td>';// Since i used fetch_row[0] I now know how many rows I have. If $start + 3 is less than the $count query
    }                                                                 // than you will have a next button. If that number exceeds the number of rows I have, then no next button.

echo "</tr>";    
echo "</table>";
```

In the code above, the ...->fetch_row()[0];  is the section that is bringing back the error. PHP 5.2.0 does not like it.

Comment: I'm fairly sure "PHP 5.2.0 does not like it." is not the error message. Always share the exact error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to PHP 5.4, you [could not dereference arrays returned from function calls](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php).  Simply do:

```
$count = mysqli_query(...)->fetch_row();
$count = $count[0];
```